# SQL Access -- Keep record only with most recent timestamp

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table that appears as follows:

```
Time    Name    Cust_ID   Num_Calls   Num_Orders

12.00   ABC     100       20           10

12.25   PQR     102       23           12

12.30   ABC     100       26           15

01.00   ABC     100       26           18

02.00   PQR     102       23           14

04.00   PQR     102       25           20
```

How do I delete the earlier records for each "Name & Cust_ID" and keep the most recent one. The other fields in the record may change as I run them through my Access Database, but Name and ID remains the same.

My output at the End of the Day should be:

```
Time    Name    Cust_ID   Num_Calls   Num_Orders

01.00   ABC     100       26           18

04.00   PQR     102       25           20
```

Comment: Do these tables have an ID column?

Comment: how do you distinguish between AM and PM on the column Time?

Comment: Yeah the tables have a normal Reference ID column, its like a serial no.

Comment: As for AM PM, I used the now() function, so it gives me the time in that format. I just used the simple numerals here as an example n simplicity

Answer (score 0):

I think if your cust_id is unique, you should make it a primary key in the table.
Then whenever you have a new entry, first check and see if the current cust_id already exists.
If yes, update that entry in the table.
Else do an insert.

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL Access programming, if you could help me with a sample code, would be great

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Cust_ID='SomeValue')
    UPDATE YourTable SET (...) WHERE Cust_ID='SomeValue'
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

This should give you your most recent records based on `max(time)`, you could delete the complement of this set.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE A
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT MAX(time) MAX_time
, NAME , CUST_ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY 
NAME , CUST_ID )B
ON A.NAME=B.Name
and A.CUST_ID=B.CUst_ID
and A.time =B.max_time
```

---

So you would delete the following records

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE B
 WHERE TIME <>( SELECT MAX(time) FROM YOUR_TABLE C WHERE B.NAME=C.Name
and C.CUST_ID=B.CUst_ID )
AND A.NAME=B.Name
and A.CUST_ID=B.CUst_ID)
```

Comment: interesting... I have never tried to use a CTE in MS Access.

Comment: I am dubious that Access supports CTE.

Comment: My bad. Changed it to a sub query.

Comment: okay. this looks better, but I am not sure if the time column shown in the example can support this.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking for a delete statement.

Comment: I tried the above code, but it gives me a SYNTAX error in the FROM clause. My time stamp is in this format, "4/3/2014 3:22:34 PM".

Comment: Updated code. I had a unneeded alias in the delete statement

Comment: When I run the first part of code, it asks me for a "Parameter Value" for max_time and B.max_time?

Comment: Hi, the code works...thanks...another question, how do I insert these values into a new table.

Comment: You mean the rows you are trying to detele? if yes, simply replace the `delete` keyword with `SELECT * `